# How to set BigQuery configuration properties with google-api-python-client?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

The project I'm working in is still using [google-api-python-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/) which is deprecated and the official documentation has no examples for it. I've gotten BigQuery working with it but I can't seem to figure out how to set [configuration properties](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.priority), specifically so that I can run a query with BATCH priority.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/sync_query.py#L28) is what you are looking for, just add the query priority field to the dict definition and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `jobs().insert()` rather than `jobs().query()`. Inserting a new job asynchronously gives the caller the ability to specify a wide range of options but requires them to run another command to get the results.

So assuming `gs` is your authenticated service object:

```
# insert an asynchronous job
jobr = gs.jobs().insert(projectId='abc-123', body={'configuration':{'query':{'query':'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table'}}}).execute()
# get query results of job
gs.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId='abc-123', jobId=jobr['jobReference']['jobId']).execute()
```